# In VueJS is there a way to read environmental variables or config values into a static/ file during build step

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables, static-files

**Background:**

Using VueJS, specifically in regards to PWA template https://github.com/vuejs-templates/pwa

There is a build step `npm run build` which bundles the project and transpiles any Vue into a distribution browser JS.

The files in /static/ are "static" and just copied into `dist`, but I am wondering if it's possible to template it at all, or read in some dynamic values.

**Question:**

Is it possible to have static files that servce under /static in the url, but also during build can accept dynamic values?

**More context:**

The problem is Vue compiles everything into the dist directory.

All non-static assets are cached and get a unique url each build, whereas static files (I know this is configurable, but you arguably want your non-static assets to have caching) have absolute paths.

Server Routing to map a file in /static/ to a cached dynamic file is outside of Vue. The question pertains to needing to host some "absolute pathed files" (static), but some files might have internally 1-2 urls that need to change in the files depending on what config is used, dev, prod, staging.. just as an example of the use case.

Comment: Why would you not do that in `src`?  The purpose of `static` is pretty clear.  If you put something dynamic in `static` your fellow developers are going to curse you later on.  Please give a concrete use case.

Comment: The problem is Vue compiles everything into the dist directory. All non-static assets are cached and get a unique url each build, whereas static files (I know this is configurable) have absolute paths. To achieve what you're suggesting we would need access to Server Routing to map a file in /static/ to a cached, dynamic file. This is outside of Vue, and not possible for us right now.

For this question, it's needed to host some "static" files, but some of them might have say 1-2 urls that need to change in the files depending on what config is used, dev, prod, staging...

Comment: That's really useful information for this question.  Please edit your question to include it.  Comments should be considered ephemeral and subject to deletion over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to use `CopyWebpackPlugin` which comes natively inside `build/webpack.prod.conf.js`

This is the plugin that copies files from static into dist/static.

You can use the `process.env.NODE_ENV` to allow you to copy specific files from static into dist.

I decided just to keep environment specific copies of the files with values changed, but you could easily add code to that file to parse and copy over whatever specific files you want.

Comment: I made the same way, i got after copy need js file in build dir. But how to read them after? How to get them from my code?

Comment: Hey Dmitrij, can you provide some more context to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think most people put dynamic configuration values in a file under public/ then use javascript fetch to load those values in Vue components. Webpack will copy the files in public/ to the web root (dist/) and it will avoid compiling those config values into the minified javascript. If you put files in static/ and use `import` or `require` to load them into Vue components then webpack will resolve those during build time and compiling them into the minified Javascript - which is probably not what you want.